# Question about lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,t) = |\sin x| + t $

Question: Does $f(x,t)$ satisfy the lipschitz condition on the entire $tx-$ plane??

So far I have

$$ | f(t,x) - f(t,v) | = ||\sin x | - | \sin v | | $$

But, I dont know how to find a bound for this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that:

$$||\sin x|-|\sin v||  \leq |\sin x- \sin v|$$ and then,

$$|\sin x- \sin v|\leq |x-v| $$

So yes, this satisfies the lipschitz condition with lipschitz constant 1. This is said to be a globally lipschitz continuous function of u uniformly in t.